# Rest Assured test passed when debugging, fails when running

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

Ok, so I have a test here that will download a zip folder from a restAPI and then extract the files and compare them against some local files to ensure they are equal and correct. All that is ok, however my problem is with downloading the Zip folder now, the zip folder will download as the response from a get request to the endpoint. So I have a few quick methods.

This first method is setting up the request to the apps homepage basically, just setting up. It's in its own method to reuse of course;

```
public RequestSpecification downloadRequest(String testRunName){
    RequestSpecification request = given()
            .baseUri(url)
            .config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames()))
            .cookies(cookiesSpecification())
            .header("Authorization", getAuthenticationToken("Automation@smart.com", "Automation0"))
            .header("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
            .param("resultsPerPage", 10)
            .param("pageNum", 1)
            .param("names", testRunName);

    return request;
}
```

Next I have a method which will take in the ID and name of test runs and will find the ID of this specific test run, this is found in the response. This method works fine:

```
public String getTestDataID(int testRunID, String testRunName) {
    log.debug("Downloading Test Data Template");

    RequestSpecification request = downloadRequest(testRunName);

    ResponseBody response =request
            .when()
            .get("/restapi/testRuns/" + testRunID + "/testData").getBody();

    String testDataID = response.jsonPath().getString("id");

    return testDataID;
}
```

Lastly, the method that keeps failing on me, will take the ID found from the previous and send a get request to the endpoint using this ID in the url. This should then download the zip folder. I return the response and then have another method converting and streaming the zip, that's all ok. The problem is with this method, I am getting Http: 500 internal server error every time I run the tests. However if I put a break point in here and step over from this method onwards it will pass.

```
public Response getTestDataZip(String testDataID){
    return getRequest(url + "/restapi/downloads/" + testDataID + "/content");
}
```

Any ideas why this would fail when running but pass if I break point it and step over each step. Due to it passing when I step over, it makes me feel like it's a cache issue, but then it is a 500 error, so maybe some authorisation which all seems to be in place ok.

If someone knows something or can see something, that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what is the error that is happening?

Comment: Well the error that will eventually happen is a null pointer exception. This is but I have since discovered that the reason the later method is returning null is because these methods return a 500 - internal server error.